# How to start maximized gui with qt-neovim?

Tags: neovim

I am using neovim with qt-neovim (linux arch).
On gvim I could launch a maximized window with:

```
if has("gui_running")
    set lines 999 columns 999
endif
```

That is not working now though. I tried removing the `if` without success.
Is there any way I can achieve that?

Comment: You should create an issue for that at their bugtracker. neovim tries  to be compatible with vim, so this should just work.

Comment: See also [How to set the size of the GUI?](http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/6844/622)

Answer (score 6):

Try putting

```
call rpcnotify(0, 'Gui', 'WindowMaximized', 1)
```

in your `ginit.vim`. I haven't tested on Linux, but it works on Windows 7.

Comment: This answer works on the Xubuntu LTS 18.04 GNU/Linux distribution.

Answer (score 2):

The reason seems to stem from the fact that neovim sets `gui_running` only *after* your `.vimrc` is sourced ([see here](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/2216)).
 [In this discussion](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/3646) it is proposed to use the `GUIEnter` event, thus a solution could be

```
autocmd GUIEnter * set lines=999 columns=999
```

Comment: Didn't work. Maybe event is not being called.

Comment: @cdvv7788 does invoking vim with `--cmd 'let gui_running="y"'` together with setting `columns` and `rows` inside an `if` using `if exists('gui_running')` work?