# How to set the size of the Neovim-qt GUI?

Tags: neovim, neovim-qt

I am using [neovim-qt](https://github.com/equalsraf/neovim-qt) but cannot figure out how to set the size of the window.  I tried:

```
nvim-qt -h
nvim-qt --help
nvim-qt --width=80
nvim-qt --geom 80x120
```

But nothing gave me any indication as to how to do it. The [wiki](https://github.com/equalsraf/neovim-qt/wiki) is equally unhelpful.

---

See [issue 108: How should window resizing behave?](https://github.com/equalsraf/neovim-qt/issues/108).

Comment: Also see another question asking essentially the same thing -- http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/5901/15

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oh look, `--geometry` is a [QT GUI application's main settings](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qguiapplication.html) thus

```
nvim-qt --geometry 500x320
```

will create a windows just big enough to have 24 lines of 80 characters.

Answer (score 2):

you can create a shortcut for nvim-qt.vim and change the target to something like `C:\tools\neovim\Neovim\bin\nvim-qt.exe -qwindowgeometry 1030x608`

and the window becomes the size you specified.

Answer (score 0):

By changing the command via regedit, you are able to use the aforementioned `qwindowgeometry` flag without having to create a new shortcut.

To set the startup width and size you can open regedit (`win +r`, type `regedit`) and go to
`Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\nvim-qt.exe\shell\open\command` and change it to something like `"C:\Program Files\nvim\bin\nvim-qt.exe" "%1" -qwindowgeometry 1024x768`

Remember to close regedit to have the change applied.

Tip from post in referenced issue [108: How should window resizing behave?](https://github.com/equalsraf/neovim-qt/issues/108)